# Synthesis(If the answer below is correct?)

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Is there any difference in the below two sentences? (synthesis)

Use much to transform the sentence:
Mother needs to be very patient when talking to her teenage daughter.

Much patience is needed by Mother when talking to her rebellious daughter.

Much patience is needed when Mother is talking to her rebellious daughter.

Comment: They're both very awkward: why use passive? But in answer to your question: in principle they are different, because the first says that it is Mother that needs patience, in the second it does not specify who needs patience. In most cases they are probably the same, but if this story is about somebody waiting to talk to Mother when she's finished with her daughter, then they could be different.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are differences.

Your first sentence means:

"***Mother** needs patience when **someone** talks to her teenage daughter*". It's strongly implied mother is doing the talking, but it's not explicit.

The second one means:

"***Someone** needs patience when **mother** talks to her teenage daughter*". It could mean mother needs patience, but it's not implied.

Both sentences are very awkward and sound like transliterations from another language, perhaps Chinese.

Also, the original sentence means:

"***Mother** needs patience when **she** talks to her teenage daughter*", unambiguously.